# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'style' on string 'wtd_background_image'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

My wordpress plugin works with fabric.js 1.2.0, When I change it to work with fabric.js 1.7.9 then it throws the error on all the pages other than plugin page:

> Cannot create property 'style' on string 'wtd_background_image'

on the following line:

```
canvasObj= new fabric.Canvas('wtd_background_image');
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to create an HTML Canvas Element with an id `wtd_background_image`, on all your pages.

```js
let canvas = new Canvas('wtd_background_image');
let canvasObj = new fabric.Canvas('wtd_background_image');

function Canvas(id) {
    this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    this.canvas.id = id;
    document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
    return this.canvas;
}

// for demonstration
let circle = new fabric.Circle({radius: 20, fill: '#07C', left: 30, top: 30});
canvasObj.add(circle);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.9/fabric.min.js"></script>
```